# Formula to substitute alphanumeric digits in a code for descriptions in prose format

Tags: excel, formula

I need to find a formula which substitutes each digit of a code for a description and to make it appear as concatenated text.

For example:

"134B2"- "Older, Tall, Richer, Bad, Boy"

"1324B" -"Older, Tall, Boy, Richer, Bad"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an User Defined Function you can have a play with.

`Arg1  stringToDecode` The string to convert. You can also pass the range address holding the string

`Arg2  keys`  This is the keys part of the cipher. Must be passed as a comma separated list.

`Arg2  values` This is the corresponding values part of the cipher.  Must be passed as a comma separated list.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Debug.Print GetCodedOutput([A1], "1,3,4,B,2", "Older,Tall,Richer,Bad,Boy")
End Sub

Public Function GetCodedOutput(ByVal stringToDecode As String, ByVal keys As String, ByVal values As String)
    Dim arr1() As String, arr2()  As String, dict As Object, i As Long, outputString As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arr1 = Split(keys, ",")
    arr2 = Split(values, ",")

    If UBound(arr1) <> UBound(arr2) Or stringToDecode = vbNullString Then
        GetCodedOutput = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        dict(arr1(i)) = arr2(i)
    Next i

    Dim outputArr(), upper As Long
    upper = Len(stringToDecode)
    ReDim outputArr(1 To upper)
    For i = 1 To upper
        On Error GoTo errhand
        outputArr(i) = dict(Mid$(stringToDecode, i, 1))
    Next
    GetCodedOutput = Join$(outputArr, ",")
    Exit Function
errhand:
    GetCodedOutput = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Exit Function
End Function
```

---

UDF in sheet:

[image]

Comment: And feedback on this?

Comment: "A value is not available to the formula or function."

Comment: No. I use ";" instead of ",". Just corrected in the code and now is working! Thanks!